# Accessing information on the internet

Tags: android, jsoup

I have this code inside my onCreate

```
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    HttpHelper helper = new HttpHelper("http://www.pinoyfitness.com/");
    helper.execute();
```

And I have this method outside the onCreate

```
private class HttpHelper extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String urlString;
    public HttpHelper(String urlString) {
        this.urlString = urlString;
    }

    public String downloadText() {
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream in = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        int charRead;
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");

        char[] inputBuffer = new char[2000];

        try {
            while((charRead=isr.read(inputBuffer))>0){
                str.append(String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead));
                inputBuffer = new char[2000];
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        urlConnection.disconnect();

        return str.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // This commented code will run the conventional way to connect to the
        // return downloadText();

        String s = "";

        try {
            // The next line does what downloadText() does. You'll need JSoup for this.
            Document d = Jsoup.connect(urlString).timeout(0).get();
            Elements links = d.select("h2.entry-title a");


            for(Element e: links){
                s += e.text() +"\n\n"; 
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return s;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.onPostExecute(result);
        tv.setText(result);
    }


}
```

The error is here: `Document d = Jsoup.connect(urlString).timeout(0).get();`. It says: at com.example.pinoyfitness.Timeline$HttpHelper.doInBackground(Timeline.java:115)
I wonder what is wrong with this line of code. I tried copy and pasting this whole code into a new android project and it works. I have done all the necessary actions such as adding internet permission and configuring build path: Jsoup

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving on that statement?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the error. It was a null pointer exception since I forgot to check the imported Jsoup in the Java Build Path -> Order and Export

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider using a network library, it will vastly improve your code and get rid of these errors.
For example, use [OkHTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) or [Android Async HTTP](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)